# Не удается выполнить привязки исполняющей среды по нулевой ссылке

Tags: c#

Есть некое условие if в котором сказано что если Вася принёс яблоки Пете, значит Петя даст Васе Арбуз, суть в том, что в мире PHP  если Вася не принесёт яблоки Пете, то он просто пойдёт дальше заниматься своими делами, но в мире C# Петя не сможет есть и пить, пока Вася не принёсет ему эти самые яблоки, причём не важно сколько, главное чтобы не 0.

А если серьёзно, то:
`RespFriends.error.error_code` - который всегда существует, но последние 2 значения могут быть а могут и не быть, когда они есть - всё нормально, но когда их нет - происходит ошибка.

```
if (@RespFriends.error.error_code == 14)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ура!");
}
```

Как мне отключить её или заставить компилятор поумнеть ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `RespFriends` или `RespFriends.error` равно `null`, то `RespFriends.error.error_code` приводит к ошибке типа `NullReferenceException`. Надо добавить условия для этих случаев:

```
if(RespFriends != null && 
   RespFriends.error != null && 
   RespFriends.error.error_code == 14)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ура!");
}
```

И в C# 6.0 есть новый оператор `?.`, называется [null propagation operator <sup>(английский)</sup>](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/). Если используете C# 6, можно делать просто так:

```
if (RespFriends?.error?.error_code == 14)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ура!");
}
```

Comment: Собачку можно убрать, автор явно пытался заглушить ошибку. :)

Comment: @Discord Так, исправил. А я подумал, что это просто часть имени переменной. Что делает собачка в C#? Я это первый раз вижу.

Comment: Собачка в C# экранирует ключевые слова, превращая их в обычные идентификаторы. Можно таким образом объявить переменные или поля с именами `if`, `while` и т.п.